# for loop inside a function being called in another function's for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, selection-sort

I'm trying to implement selection sort with javascript, but it seems that either i'm missing something or doing something absolutely wrong.
as you may understand from a first look, `sortArray()` seems to return `arr` with only one value `5` while it should return an array with as such `[5,5,5,5,5,5]`.
worth mentioning is that when I comment line `smallest_index = find_smallest(nums)`
I get the supposed input; `[5,5,5,5,5,5]`.

```js
let nums = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function sortArray(nums) {
  let arr = new Array();
  let smallest_index;
  for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    smallest_index = find_smallest(nums);
    arr.push("5");
  }

  return arr;
}

function find_smallest(arr) {
  let smallest = arr[0];
  let smallest_index = 0;

  for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < smallest) {
      console.log("this");
      smallest = arr[i];
      smallest_index = i;
    }
  }
  return smallest_index;
}

console.log(sortArray(nums));
```

any help or thoughts as to what i may be not be realizing or doing ?

Comment: Make `i` a local variable in each function. `find_smallest()` is updating the variable `i` that's used in `sortArray()`, so the loop ends after the first iteration.

Comment: E.g. `for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)`

Comment: @Barmar works! thanks for pointing that out, seems i had forgotten `let` exists for a reason :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is within your for loops. More specifically, you need to declare the variable i before using it. If you alter your code like the below snippet, then your code works just as expected:

```js
let nums = [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function sortArray(nums) {
  let arr = new Array();
  let smallest_index;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    smallest_index = find_smallest(nums);
    arr.push("5");
  }

  return arr;
}

function find_smallest(arr) {
  let smallest = arr[0];
  let smallest_index = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < smallest) {
      console.log("this");
      smallest = arr[i];
      smallest_index = i;
    }
  }
  return smallest_index;
}

console.log(sortArray(nums));
```

The only difference is using

```
for (let i = 1; ...
```

instead of

```
for (i = 1; ...
```